# issubclass() arg 1 must be a class - How to pass parameter from Inline to Form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

In order to avoid code duplication, I want to pass parameter from inline to form, but I got an error.

My `Inline`:

```
class SportUserCriteriasInlineAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
    model = CTSportOrPlaceTypesToCriteriasGroups
    form = CriteriaChoicesFieldForm('user')
```

My `Admin`:

```
@admin.register(SportTypesGroups)
class SportTypeGroupsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SportUserCriteriasInlineAdmin]
```

My `Form`:

```
class CriteriaChoicesFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user_or_team, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CriteriaChoicesFieldForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if user_or_team == 'user':
            # DO SOMETHING

    class Meta:
        model = CTSportOrPlaceTypesToCriteriasGroups
        fields = '__all__'
```

The line `inlines = [SportUserCriteriasInlineAdmin]` generates error:

```
  File "/home/sweetuser/www/sportproject/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 255, in _check_form
    if hasattr(obj, 'form') and not issubclass(obj.form, BaseModelForm):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

So, the parameter actually is passed (I checked via `print()`), but for some reason there is a problem in `admin` part.

Comment: You are instantiating the form in the third line of your Inline class. At that stage the admin expects a form class, not a form object. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin. I suspect it's that that is being checked in `checks.py`

Comment: You could do something similarly DRY by subclassing   `CriteriaChoicesfieldForm` to `UserCriteriaChoicesfieldForm` and  `TeamCriteriaChoicesfieldForm`, and having them differ only in their `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at some of the rest of your code here, but how about this?

admin.py:

```
class SportUserCriteriasInlineAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
    model = CTSportOrPlaceTypesToCriteriasGroups
    form = UserCriteriaChoicesFieldForm


class SportTeamCriteriasInlineAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
    model = CTSportOrPlaceTypesToCriteriasGroups
    form = TeamCriteriaChoicesFieldForm


@admin.register(SportTypesGroups)
class SportTypeGroupsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SportUserCriteriasInlineAdmin]
```

forms:

```
class CriteriaChoicesFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CTSportOrPlaceTypesToCriteriasGroups
        fields = '__all__'


class UserCriteriaChoicesFieldForm(CriteriaChoicesFieldForm):
    def __init__(self, user_or_team, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserCriteriaChoicesFieldForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # DO SOMETHING
```

Comment: Where\how do you pass `'user'` from `inline` to `form`?

Comment: I intended that by choosing `SportUserCriteriasInlineAdmin` instead of `SportTeamCriteriasInlineAdmin` you effectively achieve the same thing. The former uses `UserCriteriaChoicesFieldForm` and the latter `TeamCriteriaChoicesFieldForm`. The `User…` variant of that form does the extra processing in its `__init__` that would previously have been achieved by passing that first `user_or_team` argument. This solution is fairly DRY for just two form variants, but for more variety than that then you'd need to start thinking about factories.